# Alternative for switch statement in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can someone suggest an alternative way to solve this problem, I don't want to use SWITCH statement in my code.

Class Definition:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Must[] must { get; set; }
    public Should[] should { get; set; }        
}  

public class Should 
{
    public Match match { get; set; }
    public Bool _bool { get; set; }
}

public class Must 
{        
    public Match match { get; set; }
    public Bool _bool { get; set; }
}

public class Match
{
    public string pname { get; set; }
}

public class Bool
{
    public string rname { get; set; }
}
```

Function Definition

```
public root getobject(string op)
        {
            Rootobject root = new Rootobject();

            op ="must";

            switch (op)
            {
                case "should":
                    root.should = new Should[1];
                    Should objShould = new Should();
                    objShould.match = new Match();
                    objShould.match.pname = "hello";
                    root.should[0] = objShould;
                   break;
                case "must":
                    root.must = new Must[1];
                    Must objMust = new Must();
                    objMust.match = new Match();
                    objMust.match.pname = "hello";
                    root.must[0] = objMust;
                    break;
            }                       

       return(root);
        }
```

Switch statement is an overhead an new type comes then i may need to add another condition. Can anyone suggest an alternative way of using switch statement.

Comment: was thinking of way using strategy or factory design pattern...

Comment: Wait. Why do you have different types with same properties? Isn't one sufficient?

Comment: there are lots of scope of improvement in this code.

Comment: Well you could create a `Dictionary<string, Func<RootObject>>` (once).

Comment: am using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root); method of newtonsoft library to convert into json format, and serialize method converts class name as attribute names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments under your question, I discovered it is possible to implement what **@Jon Skeet** stated.

You can add an **Initialize Method** in your **RootObject class** to create the dictionary (*Use a ref Dictionary so to avoid setting the dictionary in your RootObject class that could change the structure of your serialization*):

```
 public void Initialize(ref Dictionary<string, Func<Rootobject>> rootDic)
        {
            Func<Rootobject> shouldFunc = () =>
            {
                Rootobject root = new Rootobject();
                root.should = new Should[1];
                Should objShould = new Should();
                objShould.match = new Match();
                objShould.match.pname = "hello";
                root.should[0] = objShould;

                return root;
            };

            Func<Rootobject> mustFunc = () =>
            {
                Rootobject root = new Rootobject();
                root.must = new Must[1];
                Must objMust = new Must();
                objMust.match = new Match();
                objMust.match.pname = "hello";
                root.must[0] = objMust;

                return root;
            };
            rootDic.Add("should", shouldFunc);
            rootDic.Add("must", mustFunc);
        }
```

And then call it in your **getobject method** like so:

```
 public static Rootobject getobject(string op)
        {
            Dictionary<string, Func<Rootobject>> rootDic = new Dictionary<string,Func<Rootobject>>();
            Rootobject root = new Rootobject();
            root.Initialize(ref rootDic);

            if(rootDic.Count > 0)
            return rootDic[op].Invoke();

            return new Rootobject();
        }
```

You still going to get the same result as the solution in your question even after serializing it.